# How to deal with questions that are not related to SQA.stackexchange with an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes come accross question that I believe are not fit foe the SQA forum here on stachexchange. They may be more fit for another forum like stackoverflow or programmers stackexchange.

For example, these questions [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22738/can-you-check-this-pom-design-pattern) and [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16039/working-with-html-table-in-coded-ui) are actually asking the forum members to test the code. These I believe are more suitable for Freelance portals rather than Q&A forums.

BUT

[One of them](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22738/can-you-check-this-pom-design-pattern) does have an answer which is marked as accepted. So now, how to deal with such questions? Should they be closed or should they be allowed to be left as they are because they have an accepted answer?

Comment: I honestly do not see how the first question is not related to SQA. POM is a very basic principle to an SQA Automation Engineer and by rejecting questions asking for assistance in implementing POMs we are only hurting the asker, future visitors and ourselves long term.

Comment: It's just that the question is a code review kind of thing where the person asking the question is actually asking for code review. Based on this reason several other questions have been closed or many Ved to another forum. So if this one is really okay with SQA then so are all other code review questions and hence they shouldn't be closed or moved to another forum!

Comment: I do not think that they should be closed or moved if they are about code reviews for code pertaining to SQA. I think these questions would be more useful long term on the site than questions asking to fix my XPath. Teaching principles to automation design, not correcting a small part of a completely flawed system.

Answer (score 1):

A question is a question regardless of its answers.

If a great question had terrible answers, you wouldn't say "well I THOUGHT it was awesome, but judging by the answers I'm gonna say instead that it's garbage."

By the same token, even if an answer is useful, if the question is poor, do what you would do anyway - downvote if you feel you must, close vote if you feel you must, and flag it if you feel you must. If you're unsure, open a meta post about it.

tl;dr - Treat it exactly the same as you would as a brand new question with no answers.